# Select div text next to clicked button within table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a sample table.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>Stuff<div id="ParentID" style="display:none">145689</div></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-small">Send</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>   
</table>
```

I want to select the text within the div tag where id=ParentID that is closest to that button clicked.  I will have multiple row in the future so it has to be unique to that row.

I have right now

```
var qry =  $(this).closest('#ParentID').text();
```

Doesn't work obviously

Comment: A hint to all respondents *except me and @inversivemedia*: `parent()` method will return `<td>` element.

Comment: I wonder how often people try to execute their solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it can be done:

```
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
    var text = $(this).closest("tr").find("div").text();
    // ...
});
```

**Note** that elements should have unique IDs, so there can't be several `<div>` elements with ID *"ParentID"*. I hope you use it as example only.

Comment: @insertusernamehere `parent()` returns a direct parent of the node, while `closest()` returns an indirect parent (i.e. goes up the tree until finds the corresponding element).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
 $(this).parent('tr').find('div#ParentID').text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var dataYouWant = $(this).parent().find('div').html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, which gives the result:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().prev().children('div').text());
});
```

Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/YLcjf/2/

(I guess you should benchmark all these solutions. Not sure if 'find' has some greedy algortithm penalty associated with it)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(){

    alert($(this).parents("tr")
          .find("div#ParentID").text());  

});
```

JS Fiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/suRfG/